# Rails/Rubber can't create staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

Trying to get started with a Rails Amazon EC2 deployment using https://github.com/rubber/rubber, and I keep ending up here after attempting to create a staging server with `cap rubber:create_staging`:

```
** [out :: production.foo.com] curl: (7) couldn't connect to host command finished in 2022ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l /tmp/create_inputs'" on production.foo.com
```

I've been sticking with Rubber's [quickstart guide](https://github.com/rubber/rubber/wiki/Quick-Start), but can't solve this.  I'm using rvm, if that makes a difference to anyone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to connect to `production.foo.com`. Change your configuration to connect to the right remote server or if you are running locally in the EC2 instance you can make it `localhost`.

Make sure you setup your public ssh key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the user that you are trying to deploy as. This is to allow capistrano/rubber to do passwordless ssh authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old post here but there's another possible cause of this issue that I've just encountered so figured this might help someone else.

I had to re-create and download a new keypair for my ec2 instances.  When I moved it to `~/.ec2/gsg-keypair` I forgot to alter the permissions.

When SSH'ing directly into the instance you get the full warning, which makes debugging it easy:

> UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! permissions 0644 for 'xxxxx.pem' are
>   too open. It is recommended that your private key files are NOT
>   accessible by others. This private key will be ignored. bad
>   permissions: ignore key: xxxxx.pem Permission denied (publickey).

But when running a rubber task you simply get a generic CURL error.  If this is the case for you too just update the permissions like this:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ec2/gsg-keypair
```